# Attaching SQL Server Express DB and adding to setup project in VS2008

Tags: sql-server

1. I added an `.mdf` file through Visual Studio. I am trying to attach it to SSMS but it gives error. How to attach it? Do I always need to create them through SSMS?
2. I created an `.mdf` through SSMS and the physical path was of my `DataDirectory` of my application. It is running fine. Now I need to make Setup of this application.

   a) Am I supposed to add this database to my setup project? If yes, does my user need to attach it manually to the instance of SQL Server? My connection string uses `MyServer\SQLExpress`

   b) I tried to add this database to setup project but it says you need administrator rights for this. What is that? How to set it up? I am already using computer with administrator rights.

Please reply as I have put up the questions point wise.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like it's about to get worse. So question 1, any chance you could tell us what error it is giving. Might help us help you, maybe. Some version info for Visual Studio and sql server would be good as well. Course if you don't want to, you don't have to, someone will keep us busy with questions we can answer...

Comment: The attaching and copying issue is resolved..  Thanks. That was a version conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved..... There was a version conflict.
Thanks every body.